# Converting to upper case. Which way is more pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, case

Using Python 3. Which method is more Pythonic? Converting to uppercase:

```
guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")
guess = guess.upper()
print(guess)
```

or

```
guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ").upper()
print(guess)
```

or

```
guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")
print(guess.upper())
```

I'd also really like to know any other more efficient ways of writing this. Thanks, really appreciate the advice.

Comment: you missed: `print(guess.upper())` It depends on how are you going to use the variable guess afterwards. If it is simply a question of printing style I prefer the one in this comment

Comment: thanks joaquin I will add that in.

Comment: how about `print(input("...").upper())`. The thing about python is that all of these may be the correct one depending on what you want to do with the return value. If you don't need to use the reutrn later you needn't assign it. However you also don't need to stick everything on one line just because you can.

Answer (score 15):

It may eventually depend upon what you will do with the value but, frankly, any of these solutions is equally pythonic almost in any situation. Just use any one of them and go ahead to the real beef :)

Comment: Indeed. Thinking too much about "pythonic" stuff keeps you from actually writing the code!

Answer (score 6):

The first variant is probably better, as it invites to check user input value, which is a good security practice also in Python.

It is also more convenient when you debug the program.

Probably this may be helpful (when run at the interactive prompt):

```
import this
```

Answer (score -9):

Converting all input to uppercase is so 1970s it's not funny. It's certainly not "Pythonic", whatever that means.

Determine what you want to do with the input AFTER the print (process the uppercased input? process the original input? nothing?) and write the code accordingly.

There is no more efficient way of writing "this" than by typing it in using a keyboard.

Comment: @John-Machlin from wikipedia - A common neologism in the Python community is pythonic, which can have a wide range of meanings related to program style. To say that code is pythonic is to say that it uses Python idioms well, that it is natural or shows fluency in the language. Likewise, to say of an interface or language feature that it is pythonic is to say that it works well with Python idioms, that its use meshes well with the rest of the language.

Comment: @tathamr: As you say, a wide range of meanings.